# Remove expand event of Business Process Flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, unified-service-desk

I want to remove expand event of my business process flow. I want to achieve that because I do not want my BPF to expand at all which is their nature by default.

I am using Classic UI/Web Refresh, dynamics CRM version 8.2.

Below are the screenshot from where i remove these expand events than my logic works fine but as soon as i try to use Jquery or JavaScript to remove these events it does not work. I have tries using **off** event of Jquery or **removeEventListener** of JavaScript, but they do not work.

**The Element from where I want to remove expand Event Listener**

[image]

**The Expand event listener:**

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding event listener for your own onclick & return false, something like that? Highly unsupported

Comment: This is totally unsupported customization. I wouldn't recommend it.